# compile error trying to demonstate parent - child classes here is my code

Tags: java, class, parent-child

what i cant get is i get a compile error i don't know how to print out my results. please help compile error is as follows constructor Sphere in class Turner_Ao4Q1.Sphere cannot be applied to given types required no arguments found: double reason: actual formal argument list differ in length. 
here is my code

```
/**
 * Displays the volume and area of cone and sphere.
 * 
 * completeion 2 hours
 * 
 * @author (Jonothon Turner) 
* @version (1)
*/
 public class Turner_A04Q1
 {
 public static class RoundShape extends Turner_A04Q1
  {
    public double radius;
  }
  public static class Sphere extends RoundShape
  {
    double sarea = 4 * Math.PI * radius * radius;
    double svolume = (4 * Math.PI * radius * radius * radius) / 3;
    public double getRadius(){
     return radius;
   }    
   public void setRadius(double r){
    radius = r;
   }
   public double getSarea(){
     return sarea;
    }
   public double getSvolume()
    {
     return svolume;
    }
   public String toString()
   {
   return ("Sphere Area = " + sarea + " and Sphere Volume = " + svolume);
   }
    }
   public static class Cone extends RoundShape
   {
    public double height;
    double carea = Math.PI * radius * (height + radius);
    double cvolume = (1.0 / 3.0) * Math.PI * radius * radius * height;
   public double getRadius()
   {
       return radius;
    }  
    public void setRadius(double r){
    radius = r;
   }
   public double getHeight(){
    return height;
  }
  public void setHeight(double h){
      height = h;
    }
  public double getCarea(){
     return carea;
    }
   public double getCvolume(){
     return cvolume;
    }  
  public String toString(){
       return ("Cone Area = " + carea + " and Cone Volume = " + cvolume);
    }
   }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {        
     Sphere sphere1 = new Sphere(4.5);
     Sphere Sphere2 = new Sphere(5.6);
     Cone cone1 = new Cone(5.2, 8.5);
     Cone cone2 = new Cone(4.7, 13.7);

     System.out.println(sphere1);
     sphere1.setRaduis(7.8);
     System.out.println(sphere1);
     System.out.println(sphere2);
     sphere2.setRaduis(2.9);
     System.out.println(sphere2);
     System.out.println(cone1);
     cone1.setRaduis(4.9);
     cone1.setHeight(3.1);
     System.out.println(cone1);
     System.out.println(cone2);
     cone2.setRadius(10.1);
     System.out.println(cone2);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is . . . a lot wrong here. I think you need to start with some very very basic java/OOP tutorials. Additionally, please format your code. It's a mess, and very difficult to read at a glance. Once you do, I suspect you'll identify some glaring errors.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a constructor for Sphere that takes a double as an argument and one for Cone that takes two doubles as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Firs of all you need constructors for your `Sphere` and `Cone` classes. You could use something like this:

```
public Sphere(double radius) {
    this.radius = radius;
}
```

and

```
public Cone(double radius, double height){
    this.radius = radius;
    this.height = height;
}
```

While in your main method mainly typos are the problem. That one should work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Sphere sphere1 = new Sphere(4.5);
    Sphere sphere2 = new Sphere(5.6);
    Cone cone1 = new Cone(5.2, 8.5);
    Cone cone2 = new Cone(4.7, 13.7);

    System.out.println(sphere1);
    sphere1.setRadius(7.8);
    System.out.println(sphere1);
    System.out.println(sphere2);
    sphere2.setRadius(2.9);
    System.out.println(sphere2);
    System.out.println(cone1);
    cone1.setRadius(4.9);
    cone1.setHeight(3.1);
    System.out.println(cone1);
    System.out.println(cone2);
    cone2.setRadius(10.1);
    System.out.println(cone2);
}
```